# Using Variable in Like Operator

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to call a random row from a table where the column "activePages" features a certain id number.

For example, activePages might contain "123 456" on one row, "456 789" on another and I use the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM advertising WHERE activePages LIKE %456% ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

...To call one of those two rows at random.

I want to do this same thing, but with a variable in place of "456". Where do I need to put the % for this to work? Or am I missing another problem entirely?

This is what I have right now:

```
$getad = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM advertising WHERE activePages LIKE :id ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1');
$getad->execute(['id' => $id]);
```

Comment: Please https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: You need the wildcard on both sides, and you need to append it in the binding, or on the variable assignment. See example 6, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a quick test to verify some other posts on SO. Adding the `%` to the PHP variable works for the like comparison.

```
<?php
  $id = "%" . $searchTerm . "%";
  $sql  = "SELECT * FROM TABLE
           WHERE COLUMN LIKE :id";
  $stmt->execute([':id'=> $id]);
?>
```

Comment: In this case, I need the search term to be the id of the page, set by the URL. So when the search term itself is a variable, how do I set $id correctly? I don't think "$id = %$searchTerm%" will work, will it?

Comment: @bababababa:  you could do like this: **`$id = '%' . $variable . '%' ;`**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sort of [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) construct.

```
 WHERE COLUMN LIKE concat('%', :id, '%')
```

You can put anything you need into `CONCAT()`, so it's quite flexible.